# How to determine sigmoid function's equation from list of points?

Tags: functions, curves

I've got a list of few points and I'm trying to find the corresponding curve's representation / equation.

Here are the points:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| **`6`** | **`0`** |
| **`20/3`** (6.666666) | **`0`** |
| **`7`** | **`0.143`** |
| **`8`** | **`0.8125`** |
| **`25/3`** (8.333333) | **`1`** |
| **`9`** | **`1`** |

I already tried to use Microsoft Excel to draw the curve (in blue, using scatter plot) and find it's equation, and by tracing it's trendline (the dotted one in red), wich I used a polynomial with order **3** to draw it because it was the more representative of my need (The more I increase the order, the more it accentuates the peak (from the bottom as from the top) by making it more "pointed").

[image: excel representation]

wich give me the equation:

> y = -0.1701 **x**³ + 3.8355 **x**² - 28.112 **x** + 67.337

It somewhat correspond to my need but have 2 inconvenient:

- This trendingline is an **aproximation**, so if **x = 7** it will give `0.1482` (instead of `0.143`) and for **x = 8** it will result by `0.8218` (instead of `0.8125`).
- When displayed entirely on a site like [Graph Pottler](https://www.transum.org/Maths/Activity/Graph/Desmos.asp), we can see the curve **going from +∞ to -∞** on the Y axis.

[image: graph potler's representation of the trendingline]

I need a function who match **perfectly** the given value of my list, where `y = 0` for each x between **]-∞;20/3]** and `y = 1` for each x between **[25/3;+∞[**.

I'm **guessing** my curve would be a [Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), looking more like:
[image: representation of the ideal curve]

while keeping in the Y interval of [0;1].

I don't really need the curve, I'm looking for the formula, not in case of studies / homework but for an informatical program. And only integer number for X are revelant (I won't try to replace X by a float number).
**Is my goal achievable ? or impossible / abstract because I do lack to much mathematical level ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to fit a straight line through the points $x = 7$ and $x = 8$. The next step is to take into account that the minimum value of the function is given by $f = 0$ and the maximum value by $f = 1$. The calculation itself is quite simple. The result is:

$$f(x) = 0 \space  for  \space x \le C_1$$
$$f(x) = -4.5435 + 0.6695 \space x \space for \space \space C_1 \le x \le C_2$$
$$f(x) = 1 \space for \space C_2 \le x$$

The constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ are given by: $C_1 = 45435/6695 = 6.7864...$ and $C_2 = 55435/6695 = 8.2801...$.

Comment: That's not really what I needed but it's quite sufficient in order to make me head on !